# Updating view with a data from the method of another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to update my `UIProgressView` with some data from a method of my utility class.
Now, just because for updating my `UIProgressView`, i am holding that method in my view controller class and everything works fine. Because i can reach the loop in that method with a global variable so i can update my progress. But if i want to move this method to my utility class, what am i supposed to do to keep informed my `UIProgressView`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to redesign your utility class to be a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Here is an example of code of your utility class:

UtilityClass.h file:

```
@interface UtilityClass : NSObject

+ (UtilityClass *)sharedInstance;

- (CGFloat)awesomeMehod;

@end
```

UtilityClass.m

```
@implementation UtilityClass

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static UtilityClass *_instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[UtilityClass alloc] init];
    });
    return _instance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // Regular initialization, however keep in mind that it will be executed just once

    return self;
}

- (CGFloat)awesomeMethod
{
    return 42.0f
}

@end
```

Now from your view controller you will call

```
CGFloat progress = [[UtilityClass sharedInstance] awesomeMethod];
[self.progressView setProgress:progress];
```

keep in mind several things:

- It's one of possible approaches and I would go and read about various
  [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) that might come in handy one day
- Probably a good idea to refresh knowledge on [view controllers and the way they interact](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- For class to become a proper singleton, you also should override
  methods such as `alloc`, `init`, `initWithZone`, `dealloc`, `release`
  etc (list of methods to override will vary if you use ARC), [here is
  an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like#answer-145221) of doing that, although `dispatch_once` takes care of
  `@synchronize()` call. For now, as long as you "instantiate" you class only
  through calling `sharedInstance` class method you will be fine.